# Why the first Term is higher in energy than the second?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

P. W. Atkins writes in his book "MOLECULAR QUANTUM MECHANICS" in section 9.4 "Term symbols and spectral details"

"We shall adopt the convention that the first term is higher in energy than the second."

I am wondering why is it so. I could not understand the logic of this convention.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the book you quote has five editions, so edition you have and quote should be indicated.
Secondly, you would better provide a context, i.e. quote not just one sentence, but at least a paragraph containing this sentence.

Suddenly, the 4th edition of this book I own is clearly different from the edition you quote. "Term symbols and spectral details" is the section 7.6 (not 9.4), but I think the paragraph below contains the relevant information

> To simplify the discussion of the spectrum that arises from these
>   energy levels we need to introduce some more notation. Spectral lines
>   arise from transitions between **terms**, which is another name for energy
>   levels. The wavenumber, $\tilde{\nu}$, of a transition is the difference between
>   the energies of two terms expressed as wave numbers:
>   $$
>     \tilde{\nu} = T' - T \, .
> $$
>   A transition is denoted $T' \rightarrow T$ for emission and $T' \leftarrow T$ for
>   absorption, with the term $T'$ higher in energy than the term $T$.

So, yes, the last phrase is nothing but a convention, pretty simple one and [followed by IUPAC](http://goldbook.iupac.org/T06473.html) by the way. In principle one could write
$$
    \tilde{\nu} = |T' - T| \, ,
$$
and don't care about is the term $T'$ higher in energy than the term $T$. Alternatively, one could first rearrange the terms and subtract the smaller from the bigger one without the need to take the absolute value of the result then.

Historically, I think that convention comes down to the fact that spectral series were formulated for emission spectra, and emission occurs when an electron transitions from a higher energy state to a lower energy state. That is why all the corresponding formulas, for instance, [Rydberg formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_formula),
$$
\frac{1}{\lambda_{\mathrm{vac}}} = RZ^2 \left(\frac{1}{n_1^2}-\frac{1}{n_2^2}\right)
$$
were formulated with emission in the back of one's mind (i.e. for $n_1 < n_2$). But of course, if $T' \rightarrow T$ transition causes emission on some wavenumber, the reverse $T' \leftarrow T$ transition will cause absorption on the same wavenumber, and in principle we don't need to tune the formula to be able to calculate this wavenumber for both emission and absorption. We could calculate it only for one case which historically is emission.

Comment: Rydberg formula seems to be reasonable explanation of convention.